# Why the whole page goes blank when screen size is as mobile width?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a screen made with ReactJS, everything works fine but when screen is resized to mobile width (`sm` of `Material UI`) everything goes WhiteScreen and I can't seem to find the reason why, any help would be appreciated.

```
import { Hidden, IconButton, Typography } from '@material-ui/core'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'

import useStyles from './styles/SubscribeNewRatePlans.styles'

return (
<div className={classes.root}>
  <div className={classes.header}>
    <Hidden mdUp>
      <IconButton className={classes.backButton} onClick={onBackClick}>
        <BackIcon />
      </IconButton>
    </Hidden>
    <Typography variant="h3" className={classes.title}>
      {getTranslate('Subscribe New Rate Plans')}
    </Typography>
  </div>
  <SubscribeNewRatePlansFilters
    acc={acc}
    setacc={setacc}
    dateObject={dateObject}
    setdateObject={setdateObject}
    inputValue={searchInputValue}
    setinputVal={setsearchInputValue}
  />
  {acc && dateObject.gregorianEndDate ? (
    <SubscribeNewRatePlansItemsBox
      rateplans={filteredRatePlans}
      loading={loading}
      accName={acc?.label || ''}
      selectedRatePlans={selectedRatePlans}
      setselectedRatePlans={setselectedRatePlans}
      ChannelId={params.id}
      EndDate={dateObject.gregorianEndDate || ''}
      StartDate={dateObject.gregorianStartDate || ''}
      onSubscribe={async () => {
        await channelSubscribe({
          variables: {
            input: selectedRatePlans
          }
        })
          .then(({ data: response }) => {
            toast.success(response.subscribeChannel.message)
          })
          .catch((err) => toast.error(err.message))
      }}
      selectAllRatePlans={selectAllRatePlans}
      setSelectAllRatePlans={setSelectAllRatePlans}
      rateMultiplier={rateMultiplier}
      setRateMultiplier={setRateMultiplier}
      showSubmitPaper={showSubmitPaper}
      setshowSubmitPaper={setshowSubmitPaper}
      acc={acc?.value || ''}
      propertyCode={acc?.code || ''}
    />
  ) : null}
</div>
)
}
```

My CSS:

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core'

import { getDirection } from '../../../localization'

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {},
  header: {
  display: 'flex',
  alignItems: 'center'
},
backButton: {
  padding: '8px 8px 4px 0',
  transform: `rotate(${getDirection() === 'rtl' ? '180deg' : '0deg'})`
},
filtersContainer: {
  display: 'flex',
  flexWrap: 'wrap',
  justifyContent: 'space-between'
},
halfSizeField: {
  width: '48%',
  [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
  width: '100%'
}
  },
    searchField: {
      width: '100%'
    },
    itemsBox: {
    paddingLeft: 16,
    paddingRight: 16,
    paddingBottom: 22,
    border: '1px solid #e7e7e7',
    borderRadius: 16,
    minHeight: 350,
    [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
      height: 'unset',
      paddingRight: 0
    }
  },
  listView: {},

  title: {
    marginBottom: 20,
    marginTop: 30,
    paddingBottom: 5,
    position: 'relative',
    width: 'fit-content'
  },
  submitFormBox: {
    position: 'fixed',
    bottom: 50,
    width: '60%',
    left: 'calc(20% + 57px)',
    borderRadius: 24,
    padding: 24,
    display: 'grid',
    gridTemplateColumns: '1fr',
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default,
    [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
      width: '80%',
      left: 'calc(10% + 57px)'
    }
  }
}))

export default useStyles
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to exactly point where the issue is, but I think this can guide you to check something first.

Since you mentioned that the problem only occurs on resizing to mobile width, you should check the ones that got affected by this mechanism. For example,

```
halfSizeField: {
  width: '48%',
  [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {    <---- check if this works as intended
  width: '100%'
}
```

and

```
minHeight: 350,
[theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {    <---- check if this works as intended
  height: 'unset',
  paddingRight: 0
}
```

and

```
backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default,
[theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {    <---- check if this works as intended
  width: '80%',
  left: 'calc(10% + 57px)'
}
```

Some of them might not work as you intended, so check them individually if any of them is causing the issue.

If this is not it then you should start checking other places that are trigged on resizing. Maybe something in JavaScript files, Theme, or other CSS files.